# Use variable labels for putdocx table tablename = data(varlist), varnames

Tags: stata

If I am using the `putdocx table tablename = data(varlist)` command in Stata. Is there a way to format the table, so it displays the variable labels?

MRE:

```
input year country_txt
2001 1
2001 2
2001 3
end

label var country_txt "Country"
label define country_label 1 "Germany" 2 "Argentina" 3 "Sweden"
label value country_txt country_label

putdocx begin
putdocx paragraph, style(Heading1)
putdocx text ("Table 1")
putdocx table table3 = data(year country_txt), varnames
putdocx save Tables, replace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can manually change the content of a cell in putdocx `putdocx table table(i,j) = ("string")`. `i` stands for the cell row, `j` for the cell column. Then you can exchange the string using  `` `: var lab country_txt'") ``

```
input year country_txt
2001 1
2001 2
2001 3
end

label var country_txt "Country"
label define country_label 1 "Germany" 2 "Argentina" 3 "Sweden"
label value country_txt country_label

putdocx begin
putdocx paragraph, style(Heading1)
putdocx text ("Table 1")
putdocx table table3 = data(year country_txt), varnames
putdocx table table3(1,2) = ("`: var lab country_txt'")
putdocx save Tables, replace
```